# Sharing between Ubuntu (as virtual machine) and Windows 7 in network

Tags: windows-7, networking, ubuntu, sharing

I am using Ubuntu in Virtual Box. My host OS is Windows 7. When I open Browse Network in Ubuntu I'm unable to see any PC in Network.

All PC's are using Windows 7.

How can I see all PCs and share data between Ubuntu (as a virtual machine) and Windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly activate SMB on Windows and add some user password and permissions to use it.

Then make sure, you are in one network with your virtual pc. (for example by `ping`; You shall get IP address of Windows by `ipconfig`, of Ubuntu by `ifconfig`).  If you are not, try to reconfig your virtual network adapter.

Mount SMB volume on Ubuntu. You can do this like this:

```
 sudo mount -t cifs //myserver_ip_address/myshare ~/mnt -o username=samb_user,noexec
```

If you have any problem, you can find more information here:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaClientGuide